# не могу вывести ошибку в питоне

Tags: python, django

Делаю систему регистрации на сайте, добавил возможную ошибку в случае несовпадения паролей, но выдает ошибку: local variable 'pass_error' referenced before assignment

вьюха:

```
    from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import registrationForm


def auth(request):
    return render(request, 'access/auth.html')


def reg(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = registrationForm(request.POST)
        if password == password2:
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            pass_error = 'Пароли не совпадают'  
            


    form = registrationForm()
    context = {
        'form' : form,
        'pass_error' : pass_error,
        
    }
    return render(request, 'access/reg.html', context)
```

В конце шаблона добавил вот такую штуку:

```
<span>{{pass_error}}</span>
```

Comment: Ну да, ведь если ошибки не случилось, то никакой переменной `pass_error` не существует

Comment: как тогда быть?

Comment: Можно заранее определить словарь `context`, а в ветке `else` лишь добавлять в него ключ. Но это не `Django`-стиль. Предполагается, что для обработки ошибок вы будете пользоваться классом формы и её валидацией.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У тебя `pass_error` не определена, и если пароли будут совпадать, то переменной `pass_error` вообще не будет совпадать. Ты можешь просто в начале функции прописать, и все будет работать:

```
def reg(request):
    pass_error = ''
    ...
```